# Play2 and Intellij no main class detected

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I am trying to develop a play framework application within a sbt sub-project. The directory tree looks like this:

```
- main-project
|--sub-project
| |--app
| |--conf
| |--logs
| |--public
| |--test
|--project
|--build.sbt
```

If I try to run the play application using sbt shell with the following command

`sub-project/run`

Play starts correctly.
However, if I try to run it with the IntelliJ Run Configuration, I get the error `java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.`

Follows the first lines of log and the command launched by IJ:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:41258,suspend=y,server=n -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djline.terminal=none -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dsbt.global.base=/tmp/sbt-global-pluginstub -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -javaagent:/home/myusername/Programmi/idea-IU-173.3727.127/lib/rt/debugger-agent.jar=/tmp/capture.props -classpath /home/myusername/.IntelliJIdea2017.3/config/plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar:/home/myusername/Programmi/idea-IU-173.3727.127/lib/idea_rt.jar xsbt.boot.Boot "project sub-project" run
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:41258', transport: 'socket'
[warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: /home/luca/IdeaProjects/main-project/sub-project
[info] Set current project to sub-project (in build file:/home/myusername/IdeaProjects/main-project/sub-project/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/myusername/IdeaProjects/main-project/sub-project/}sub-project...
[info] Done updating.
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
```

It looks like the sbt command is different than expected (`sbt project sub-project run` insted of `sbt sub-project/run`)

Anyone has ever configured IntelliJ to debug a play application with the launch tool?
Thanks

Comment: can you please check my answer - comment if you still have problems or accept it otherwise? So it helps others and gives me feedback if my answer are correct or at least help.

Comment: Sorry, I never had the time to even look at it until today, as work has completely overwritten this priority. I will check now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run is usually enough in my projects - but I tried it out, like:

[image]

And it worked. My console looks like:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:55426,suspend=y,server=n -Dconfig.file=server/conf/demo.conf -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -javaagent:/Users/pascal.mengelt/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2017.3/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar=/private/var/folders/cj/t4h2s_g56w1b78ck_mp1c1w40000gp/T/capture.props -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/pascal.mengelt/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.3/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" xsbt.boot.Boot server/run
objc[15772]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10d7794c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10e8b44e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55426', transport: 'socket'
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
...
```

The whole project you find here:
[scala-adapters](https://github.com/pme123/scala-adapters/)

Comment: This run configuration works. However, I was referring to the built-in play run configuration (Maybe it's only found in IJ Ultimate Edition?) Anyway since this works I'll accept the solution until someone points out how to make the builtin config work. Thanks!

Comment: You are right - I get the same exception using the Play 2 Application. So my answer is only a workaround - but there is no disadvantage using sbt run - as you can debug as well

Comment: @Luca When I create a new Play.2 Project the Play.2 run works. Maybe this is a requirement? Can it be that you created an SBT-Project?

Comment: Yes, you get the same features using your configuration or the embedded play run. Anyway If I remember correctly I created an SBT project, you're right. But I don't think the problem is there, as the command to run the project should not change if IJ created the project or you created it by hand. I'll do a few more tries when I got time. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

@Luca: It is because of plugin version conflict between scala plugin sbt version ,activator and intellij idea.New Intellij is trying to ignore the $PROJECT_DIR files and other flougins are putting the conf files there.

Workaround:
Put this in your *play2_project_settings.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="Play2ExcludedModulesSettings">
    <option name="INFO">
      <map>
        <entry key="api">
          <value>
            <ProjectSettingsEntry>
              <option name="confDir" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/api/app" />
              <option name="templateImports">
                <list>
                  <option value="_root_.play.twirl.api.TwirlFeatureImports._" />
                  <option value="_root_.play.twirl.api.TwirlHelperImports._" />
                  <option value="_root_.play.twirl.api.Html" />
                  <option value="_root_.play.twirl.api.JavaScript" />
                  <option value="_root_.play.twirl.api.Txt" />
                  <option value="_root_.play.twirl.api.Xml" />
                  <option value="models._" />
                  <option value="controllers._" />
                  <option value="play.api.i18n._" />
                  <option value="views.xml._" />
                  <option value="play.api.templates.PlayMagic._" />
                  <option value="play.api.mvc._" />
                  <option value="play.api.data._" />
                </list>
              </option>
              <option name="routesImports">
                <list>
                  <option value="controllers.Assets.Asset" />
                </list>
              </option>
              <option name="uri" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/../../../../<custom-project-path>" />
            </ProjectSettingsEntry>
          </value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="chargeback-api">
          <value>
            <ProjectSettingsEntry>
              <option name="playDistrPath" value="$USER_HOME$/.coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play_2.12/2.6.11/play_2.12-2.6.11.jar" />
            </ProjectSettingsEntry>
          </value>
        </entry>
      </map>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

[image: Filepath]

In custom-project-path put the absolute path of your project directory it will work like a charm!!

Comment: Thank you, I will try it asap and get back to you! :)

Comment: Did this work for you?  What exactly did you change?

Comment: This worked for me: I modified the "uri" option in my play2_project_settings.xml to point to the PARENT directory, not the sub-project.

Answer (score 1):

The above two ways both work.

More detailed instructions for @frostcs 's answer:

1. Open the `play2_project_settings.xml`
2. Find the below key line:

   ```
    <option name="uri" value="/E:/jc/code/lets-build-a-blockchain/stage1" />
   ```
3. Prepend `$PROJECT_DIR$/../../../../` to `uri` value. As belows

   ```
    <option name="uri" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/../../../../E:/jc/code/lets-build-a-blockchain/stage1" />
   ```
4. It will work like a charm!!